# mysql error 1064 when changing structure of date from datetime to VARCHAR

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

There is an issue when I try to change the structure of one of the table in mysql 
It is user db table and it has many fields and one of them is register date field

It is currently set to datetime and I am trying to change it to VARCHAR using phpmyAdmin as that is the only best way I know to do it using my limited mysql / phpmyadmin expertise.

```
ALTER TABLE  abnhd_user CHANGE  registerDate  registerDate VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

when I try to change it from datetime to VARCHAR, I get following error

> `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'' at line 1`

Comment: Show your ALTER statement

Comment: please provide the query you executed.

Comment: why are you changing a date field to varchar? It is generally NOT a good idea to try and store dates in anything other than native date/datetime fields, because you lose almost ALL of mysql's built-in date "math" capabilitie.s

Comment: Hi All, @Marc, I want to change the date to VAR CHAR because when I upload the CSV to populate database with users it make date as ''0000-00-00 00:00:00' even if I have put some date in there in CSV table

Comment: then fix the csv, or upload to a temporary table and fix the bad dates there.

Comment: @Krisha , Abdul : Please the query I have copied below                      SQL query:

ALTER TABLE  `abnhd_user` CHANGE  `registerDate`  `registerDate` VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'' at line 1                               P.S : I am using phpmyadmin , I go to structure select the field click edit and try to change the registerdate column type from datetime to VARCHAR

Comment: @Marc B, it is possible that after fixing CSV I can get the desired dates shown up in the table, I tried all possible methods but my it didn't work. Please suggest what format should be used in CSV for dates. My end goal is to get the real dates show for the users and not  0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: you need to use the standard mysql format: `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`, or use something more intelligent to get the csv into mysql than `load data infile`.

Comment: Ok will give a try to above solution and come back, also attached the pic of phpmyadmin screenshot http://oi57.tinypic.com/2le5qr.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You executed query

```
ALTER TABLE  abnhd_user CHANGE  registerDate  registerDate VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

But MySQL doesn't have default value `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` for VARCHAR so use below `SQL` to change to VARCHAR

```
ALTER TABLE abnhd_user MODIFY registerDate VARCHAR(30);
```

Comment: Hi Abdul, Below is link to pic http://oi57.tinypic.com/2le5qr.jpg , Please check, How do i user alter table using phpmyadmin

Comment: Remove default value Or You can also execute SQL statement in Phpmyadmin